# Android MenuDrawer Change Size

Tags: java, android, menu, drawer

I'm using the Android [MenuDrawer](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer) from https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer in my Activity.
After Updating the Library, the Menu was a little bit smaller than before. How can I change the size (width) of the Menu?

Comment: Why don't you use Android's Drawer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MenuDrawer has a xml attribute for the size - mdMenuSize.

Alternatively you can set this programmatically too with the setMenuSize method of the menudrawer.

Comment: If i used `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, how can I change the size?

Answer (score 4):

**before on create method:**

```
private MenuDrawer mDrawer;

public static final int TOUCH_MODE_NONE = 0;
```

**After on Create method:**

mDrawer.setMenuSize(600);

600 is in dp set as u like

following is piece of my code:

```
    mDrawer = MenuDrawer.attach(this);
    mDrawer.setTouchMode(TOUCH_MODE_NONE);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;

    if(width>=640)
        mDrawer.setMenuSize(600);
    else if(width<640)
        mDrawer.setMenuSize(400);


    mDrawer.setContentView(R.layout.drawermain);
    mDrawer.setMenuView(R.layout.drawermenu);
```

Comment: shouldn't you handle the result as DP instead of pixels?